# Purpose of a2ensite and a2dissite

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I just set up my first Ubuntu dev environment and was wondering why there are 2 direcotries called sites-available and sites-enabled. After some reading I stombled acress a2ensite and a2dissite. Also I read that I have to put all my vhost stuff into sites-available and then enable it through that command.

Ok, tested it, and it works. I'm used to mac, and there I just created an vhost and the site was "enabled". There was never such a thing like disabling and enabling a site. I've read , that it is nice, because you can disable a site when it is broken very quickly...

But I don't get it. What's the purpose of the whole thing? How should it help me? Why should I use it? If there were something like a maintenanc.html for each site which it creates an link to, it would might make some sense, but since it doesn't do such a thing but just creating/deleting symlinks, i really don't get its purpose.

If i disable a site, the site isn't really down, it just servers the default vhost. Which actually makes sense due to the principle of how apache handels the whole stuff.

So, what is it, which I don't see? :)

Comment: Please read http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/20/apache-configuration-files-on-debian

Comment: Please, someone, an answer :p As @xotix, I am wondering why these 2 command exist because if they only create symlinks and print "restart apache etc.", this is not really usefull !

Comment: Maybe you have to post that question on Server Fault or Super User. I am also interested in an answer!